# How can I check my storage on my OneDrive for business account?

Tags: account-management, office-365, onedrive

How can I check my storage on my OneDrive for a business account?

https://faq.oit.gatech.edu/content/how-do-i-check-my-storage-usage-onedrive-business says:

[image]

[image]

[image]

but I don't have the "site settings" option in my setting menu:

[image]

and searching for "site" in the settings  doesn't return anything:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- log in to your account
- go to **https://onedrive.live.com/?v=managestorage**
- or click on the progress bar:

  [image]
- then you can click on **What's taking up space?**

  [image]